# Exporting wazuh graphs

Tags: kibana, wazuh

Let me start by saying that I am not very familiar with `wazuh` and `kibana`.

I am creating a web application in Angular and it is required for me to embed `wazuh` charts in it.
Example chart that I need to export:

[image]

I have been told that it is possible to do it but not how to do it. I am thinking about pulling the data from API and recreating the graphs. In order to do that I was trying to figure out what library was used in `wazuh` to create the original graphs but I failed. Do you know the library that is used to generate those graphs? Or maybe if it is proprietary solution? Maybe you know a better way to embed those graphs in a web application?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import the Alerts level evolution graph you may recreate it by creating a custom visualization. Click on the top left menu and go to the Visualize section.  Select the type of graph, an area graph in this case, and select the source, for example wazuh-alerts-*.

Add a bucket for the X axis with Date Histogram using the timestamp field, add a sub-bucket with Split series, sub aggregation Terms and field rule.level.

Once you have created and saved the visualization you may click on Share,  Embed code and copy an iframe that you can paste into your application.

You can also import full dashboards with several visualizations by creating and sharing a custom Dashboard instead.

[image]

Comment: This is it. Thank you. I upvoted but my vote doesn't count yet.